# Using Proguard to embed Guava in another jar

Tags: java, classloader, proguard

I have a Tomcat 6 server which is hosting a portlet container (in a war) and several portlets (each one packaged in its own war). We have a requirement to share data between these portlets, and due to the version of the portlet container we are using, the only way that we can see to do this is to place a jar with our logic into the endorsed folder to ensure that the same instance is seen by the different wars (each one has its own classloader).

This jar makes use of the various caching functions of Google Guava and has been proven to work in unit tests and within the portlet container. However, we have found ourselves faced with a clash of different versions of Guava due to the endorsed classloader taking preference over the subsequent classloaders. The portlet container uses an early version of Guava and our portlets use our internal framework which uses a more recent version!

- If we write our endorsed jar to use the same version of Guava as the portlet container then the framework boots but the portlets won't start as the API is different.
- If we write our endorsed jar to use the same version of Guava as our own framework, then the portlet framework won't start because the API is different, so our portlets never load.

The approach we are trying at the moment is copying the Guava source code into our own jar under a new package - this has been done in various open source projects - for example the class `com.google.common.base.Ascii` would be repackaged `com.mycompany.com.google.common.base.Ascii`. This works, though it means recompiling Guava each time we make a new version of our endorsed jar.

We would prefer being able to automate the generation of this endorsed jar, and having seen documentation for using ProGuard with Guava in an Android context, have a feeling that Proguard might be able to help.

Is ProGuard capable of repackaging a jar dependency inside another jar, maintaining a single internal package hierarchy? Could the `-flattenpackagehierarchy` option do this?

Comment: How about using JarJar (https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to repackage Guava so you don't have to recompile it from source every time?

Comment: @DanDyer that looks good to me - if you want to post an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use [JarJar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to repackage Guava so you don't have to recompile it from source every time.